# Поиск слов из кортеже в списке построчно

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть кортеж в котором содержаться слова, также есть список, где в каждой строке содержится несколько предложений (размер списка может меняться), как можно построчно читать кортеж и список, сравнивая каждую строку кортежа с каждой строкой из списка, для того что бы найти строки, где слова из кортежа содержаться в списке?

кортеж = Толстой, Чехов, Пушкин, список = псевдоним Чехова был А-т Чехонте, Пушкин погиб в дуэли и тд

```
import csv 

tuples = [] 
lists = () 
povtor = 0 
with open('avtor.csv', 'r') as f: 
    read_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|") 
    for row in read_csv: 
        row = tuple(row) 
        tuples.append(row) 
with open('isk_avtors.csv', 'r') as f:
    read_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|") 
    for row in read_csv: 
        row = list(row) 
        lists = row 

for line in lists: 
    for aut in tuples: 
        if aut in lists: 
            povtor=povtor+1 
print(povtor)
```

Comment: Приведите пример данных. Параллельно перебирать коллекции можно с помощью `zip` примерно так: `for l1,l2 in zip(list1, list2)`

Comment: кортеж = Толстой, Чехов, Пушкин,
список = псевдоним Чехова был А-т Чехонте, Пушкин погиб в дуэли
и тд
'import csv

tuples = []
lists = ()
povtor = 0

with open('avtor.csv', 'r') as f:
    read_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")

    for row in read_csv:
        row = tuple(row)
        tuples.append(row)
with open('isk_avtors.csv', 'r') as f:
    read_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")

    for row in read_csv:
        row = list(row)
        lists = row
for line in lists:
    for aut  in tuples:
        if aut in lists:
            povtor=povtor+1
print(povtor)'

Comment: Я перенёс ваш код в вопрос, но не уверен в отступах

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если я правильно понял вопрос, то для уже заполненных структур будет примерно так:

```
authors = ("Толстой", "Чехов", "Пушкин")
texts = ["псевдоним Чехова был А-т Чехонте", "Пушкин погиб в дуэли", "и тд"]

found_count = sum(any(a in text for a in authors) for text in texts)
print('Найдено совпадений:', found_count)

# 2
```